# Why can't Heroku find a version of 'os' that satisfies the requirement?

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord.py

I am trying to deploy my bot on Heroku through GitHub.

In requirements.txt, I have 'os'. I tried to deploy the bot so Heroku would recognise the Procfile. It gave me this error.

```
Collecting os (from -r /tmp/build_e656b8b6627c307b02ef77c47e6bb725/requirements.txt (line 3))
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from -r /tmp/build_e656b8b6627c307b02ef77c47e6bb725/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: )
       No matching distribution found for os (from -r /tmp/build_e656b8b6627c307b02ef77c47e6bb725/requirements.txt (line 3))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include `os` in your requirements.txt - it's a built-in module. Just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to install/require `os`. It isn't on the package index, it's a built-in package.

Simply remove the `os` line from your `requirements.txt` file to fix this issue.